# <identifier expected> when declaring Random

Tags: java

I managed to get an error in just 3 lines of code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test
{
    private Random rnumber;
    rnumber = new Random();
    private int nmb = rnumber.nextInt(36);
}
```

The error is right after `rnumber`. I don't understand what is wrong.

If i change it to:

```
 private Random rnumber = new Random();
 private int nmb = rnumber.nextInt(36);
```

The error disappears, but when I add println:

```
private Random rnumber = new Random();
private int nmb = rnumber.nextInt(36);
System.out.println("" + nmb);
```

Same error comes back, but now right after `println`.

Comment: You cannot just stick random code anywhere in a `class`. Code must go in a block. Please read a basic tutorial on Java syntax...

Answer (score 3):

Put your code in some method, constructor or static initializer block, as required.

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Random rnumber;
    rnumber = new Random();
    int nmb = rnumber.nextInt(36);
  }
}
```

or

```
public class Test
{
  private Random rnumber;
  private int nmb;
  public Test ()
  {
    rnumber = new Random();
    nmb = rnumber.nextInt(36);
  }
}
```

Comment: or block (static or instance)

Comment: Now I'm feeling dumb, guess while being sleepy it's not the best time to try writing code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only instructions you have the right to execute out of a block are declarations/initializations, that's why your code compiles when you remove some lines of code which are not declarations.

Put your logic in a method or a block and it will be fine.